# override Equals Method in C#

Tags: c#

I am Trying to **override Equals Method in C#** and I am Getting Error like

**SoftCherry.Customer' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'**

*Error Line* : **return this.FirstName == ((Customer).obj).FirstName &&
                    this.LastName == ((Customer).obj).LastName;** *in Customer  Class*

and This Is My Code

```
using System;

    namespace SoftCherry
    {
        public class MainClass
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                Customer  C1  = new Customer ();
                C1.FirstName = "Raja";
                C1.LastName = "Thananki";

                Customer  C2= new Customer ();
                C2.FirstName = "Raja";
                C2.LastName = "Thananki";

                Console.WriteLine(C1== C2);
                Console.WriteLine(C1.Equals(C2));
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public class Customer 
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (obj == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!(obj is Customer))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return this.FirstName == ((Customer).obj).FirstName &&
                    this.LastName == ((Customer).obj).LastName;
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return this.FirstName.GetHashCode() ^ this.LastName.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lose the dots before `obj`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the dots after the type:

```
return this.FirstName == ((Customer)obj).FirstName &&
       this.LastName == ((Customer)obj).LastName;
```

Otherwise it is not valid syntax.

Comment: Feel free to accept any of the answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be using `(Customer)obj`, not `(Customer).obj`. You have an errant dot in there everywhere you're performing this cast.